# How to construct an increasing $\aleph_1$ sequence of real numbers.

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers, order-theory

We have $\aleph_1\leq |\mathbb{R}|$. Do we know if there exists an increasing $\aleph_1$ sequence of real numbers? (That is, a set $\{a_\theta\in\mathbb{R}:\theta<\omega_1\}$ such that $a_{\theta_1}<a_{\theta_2}$ if $\theta_1<\theta_2$.) If we know there exists such a sequence, is it possible to have some explicit example/construction?

This question arose because it was very easy for me to construct an increasing $\aleph_0$ sequence of real numbers, but once I thought about increasing $\aleph_1$ sequence, I couldn't even confirm that such a sequence exists. For an increasing $\aleph_0$ sequence, we can take $\{-\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, or just $\mathbb{N}$ it self.

Comment: This is an excellent question, but it has been asked here before. The key fact is that despite $\mathbb{R}$ being uncountable, it is in a sense built on a countable "frame," namely $\mathbb{Q}$, and this prevents any such sequence from existing.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! My question is resolved.

Comment: Incidentally, a fun follow-up puzzle is to show that this is sharp: generalizing what you've already observed for $\omega$, for any *countable* ordinal $\alpha$ there is an order-preserving embedding $\alpha\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (we can even find one whose image is closed in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$). So there really is a very stark transition from countable to uncountable going on here.